# Using .htaccess to change directory show in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change the url that show in the addressbar.
Code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^Home?$  index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^about-us?$  aboutus.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^contact?$  contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^products?$  products.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^products/led-bulb?$  led-bulb.php [NC,L]
```

Explain: All page in the same directory and 4 first rewrite rule is ok, but the last rewrite rule has problem.(products/led-bulb directory not exist).
Problem: last rule when loaded the [led-bulb.php] it not loaded any style and show the page without any style and design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last rule is also working fine but you are facing style/image display problem due to your use of relative paths.

You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Also your rules should be making trailing slash optional like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Home/?$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us/?$ aboutus.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^products/led-bulb/?$  led-bulb.php [NC,L]
```